# Python treetaggerwrapper returns a binary invalid error :tree-tagger.exe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, nlp, anaconda

I have downloaded the treetagger wrapper for python from pip to use it for POS tagging purposes, Also i have downloaded the official Treetagger application from http://www.smo.uhi.ac.uk/~oduibhin/oideasra/interfaces/winttinterface.htm

Also I have downloaded the language model file for english the one with the name "english-bnc.par", which I later renamed it to "english-utf8" as per the encoding support in python 3.

Also I have included the TreeDirectory path using the TAGDIR argument while creating TreeTagger Object.

Now I get a error saying invalid binary !

I am a newbie to python and natural language processing , So if anyone have come across this issue please do let me know, Thanks in advance [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLbt6.png)

Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import pprint
> > >       import treetaggerwrapper
> > >       C:\Users\ranak_viod5a3\Anaconda3\treetaggerwrapper.py:740: FutureWarning: Possible nested set at position 8
> > >         re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)
> > >       C:\Users\ranak_viod5a3\Anaconda3\treetaggerwrapper.py:2044: FutureWarning: Possible nested set at position 152
> > >         re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE)
> > >       C:\Users\ranak_viod5a3\Anaconda3\treetaggerwrapper.py:2067: FutureWarning: Possible nested set at position 409
> > >         UrlMatch_re = re.compile(UrlMatch_expression, re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE)
> > >       C:\Users\ranak_viod5a3\Anaconda3\treetaggerwrapper.py:2079: FutureWarning: Possible nested set at position 192
> > >         EmailMatch_re = re.compile(EmailMatch_expression, re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE)
> > >       tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG='en',TAGDIR='C:/TreeTagger/bin')
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "C:\Users\ranak_viod5a3\Anaconda3\treetaggerwrapper.py", line 1006, in **init**
> > >           self._set_tagger(kargs)
> > >         File "C:\Users\ranak_viod5a3\Anaconda3\treetaggerwrapper.py", line 1072, in _set_tagger
> > >           raise TreeTaggerError("TreeTagger binary invalid: " + self.tagbin)
> > >       treetaggerwrapper.TreeTaggerError: TreeTagger binary invalid: C:\TreeTagger\bin\bin\tree-tagger.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem of "treetaggerwrapper.TreeTaggerError: TreeTagger binary invalid: /TreeTagger/cmd/bin/tree-tagger" and I downloaded TreeTagger from https://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/

I solved it by copying the whole /bin directory to /cmd.